How to evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{e^{x/y}-e}{x-y}$?

How to evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{e^{x/y}-e}{x-y}$?

I first set $y=1$ and found that the limit equals $e$. Then I set $x=1$ and also found that the limit is $e$. So I thought the I would converge to some value. However, I'm confused about how to prove the limit converges to some value. Delta epsilon proofs are long and I don't think I can apply that technique on a test. Any more efficient method would be nice.
Any help would be appreciated.

If use $x-y=y(x/y-1)$ and let $r=x/y,$ the becomes $$\lim_{(r,y)\to(1,1)} \frac1y\frac{e^r-e}{r-1}$$ Clwaarly $\frac1y\to1,$ and the second term has a limit equalit to $e,$ since it is just the derivative of  $e^x$ at $x=1.$

@RyszardSzwarc Usually, according to the more general definition of limit, we implicitely exclude such points. Therefore I don’t think this addendum is necessary or useful.

Evaluating a multivariable limit based on a few paths to the limit point is generally not a good way to find a limit.  If the limit exists, this technique will find the limit.  But, it could be the case that the limit does not exist yet all of your test paths converge to the same value.

Using the idea suggested in the comments, with $x/y-1\to 0$, by standard limits
$$\frac{e^{\frac x y}-e}{x-y}=\frac e y\frac{e^{\frac x y-1}-1}{\frac x y-1}\to \frac e1\cdot 1=e$$

It is not an "alternative". It is exactly @ThomasAndrews' solution.

@AnneBauval Can we say similar? Since here we are using standard limit while the other way is by derivatives.

His derivative is just one (usual) way to justify the standard limit you both use.

@AnneBauval In the way I’ve studied real analysis, standard limits are treated before derivatives, in this case this was obtained from the foundamental $(1+1/n)^n\to e$.
